# find out the zip uncompressed file size from aws s3 bucket

Tags: php, zip, filesize, compression

I want to find out uncompress size of zip file which is stored in aws s3 bucket. How can we find out in php?

In local server i find out using exec('unzip -l filename.zip') in php.

Answer (score 0):

You are uncompressing a zip to find out the size?.. That's a bit overkill..

Here's some code to help you along, loading the zip, iterating through each entry to get the uncompressed size and return it.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('myzip.zip')) {
    var_dump(getTotalUncompressedSize($zip));
    $zip->close();
}

function getTotalUncompressedSize(ZipArchive $zip)
{
    $totalSize = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $fileStats = $zip->statIndex($i);
        $totalSize += $fileStats['size'];
    }

    return $totalSize;
}
```

Comment: but my zip file not on local server, which is stored on amazon aws s3 server. So i need to download it or not?

Comment: So there is no php/site running on the server? it's just cloud storage?

Comment: yes there is just a cloud storage. if i put url of s3 bucket file in
$file_name = "path_of_s3_file_url";
 if ($zip->open($file_name)) {
    var_dump(getTotalUncompressedSize($zip));
    $zip->close();
}
But it not read file from s3 bucket.

Comment: yeh I won't read a zipfile from across the internet, that makes a bit more tricky - if you upload the zips yourself to aws then I suggest you store the zipname/size in a database?